# What does void *(*routine)(void *) mean in C?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, function-pointers, argument-passing

I'm learning C and I came to this expression:

```
void *(*routine)(void *)
```

I find it very confusing. Maybe it's a pointer...to a pointer... to a pointer?

If I wanted to pass this thing into a function, how would we manipulate it? I am trying to pass this routine construction as a parameter to a function that takes a `void(*)(void)`... but I am rather lost on what that actually means.

Comment: In cases like this [http://cdecl.org/](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+*%28*routine%29%28void+*%29) is your friend.

Comment: cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+*%28*routine%29%28void+*%29

Comment: Please note that cdecl started as a command-line tool, and it's available many places.  You don't have to use a website to use cdecl.

Comment: @PinkElephantsOnParade - Just so you know and in case it is the case I thought to mention that this specific signature is used as part of the pthread_create API: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
void *(*routine)(void *);
```

declares a pointer to function that takes argument of type `void *` and returns pointer of type `void *`

---

Simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* foo(void* x) {
    printf("Hello.");
}

int main(void) {
    void *(*routine)(void *);
    routine = foo;              // assings foo to our function pointer
    (*routine)(NULL);           // invokes foo using this pointer
    return 0;
}
```

outputs: `Hello.`

---

*"If I wanted to pass this thing into a function"* ~ here is example 2 for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* foo(void* x) {
    printf("Hello.");
}

typedef void *(*RoutinePtr)(void *);           // alias to make your life easier

void routineInvoker(RoutinePtr routine) {
    (*routine)(NULL); // invokes the routine
}

int main(void) {
    RoutinePtr routine = foo;   // creates a function pointer
    routineInvoker(routine);    // and passes it to our invoker
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 41):

Start with the leftmost identifier and work your way out, remembering that absent explicit grouping with parentheses, `[]` and function call `()` bind before `*`, so

- `*a[N]` is an N-element array of pointers
- `(*a)[N]` is a pointer to an N-element array
- `*f()` is a function returning a pointer
- `(*f)()` is a pointer to a function

So,

```
        routine             -- routine
       *routine             -- is a pointer
      (*routine)(      )    -- to a function
      (*routine)(void *)    -- taking a single parameter of type void *
     *(*routine)(void *)    -- returning a pointer
void *(*routine)(void *)    -- to void
```

Comment: +1 For clean and lovely explanation of how to read declarations :)